# What will this do? C++

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

```
void main()
{
    int const *p=5;
    cout<<++(*p);
}
```

What will this do? Is it wrong and if so, why? Please make me understand. Thank you!

Comment: It will get you downvotes mostly. To avoid those in the future you should  take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Here is [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: What did i do wrong? I am new here, please explain! Thanks

Comment: What does your compiler say when you try to compile this piece of code?

Comment: _What did i do wrong?_ Well.. For starters - you didn't do _any_ research before asking here.

Answer (score 2):

> What will this do?

The program is ill-formed and may refuse to compile. If it compiles, the behaviour is not specified by the standard.

> Is it wrong and if so, why?

It is. Because:

> ```
> error: '::main' must return 'int'
> error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const int*'
> error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
> error: increment of read-only location '* p'
> ```